# sql join 4 table and return all fields

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Hi I have the following entities:

**TABLE`USER`**:

`id_user
 Name
 Username
 role`

**TABLE`TASK`**:

`id_task
 task_Name
 tipe`

**TABLE `COMPLETED_TASK`**:

`id_task
 id_user`

**TABLE`ASSIGNED_TASK`**:

`id_task
 id_user`

Is there any way to get a complete list of task **"completed and assigned"** along with the corresponding user?

I tried the following query but this doesn't work exactly as it failed to  return all `TASK.id_task`

```
SELECT * FROM TASK 
LEFT  OUTER  JOIN COMPLETED_TASK ON TASK.id_task=COMPLETED_TASK.id_task 
LEFT  OUTER    JOIN ASSIGNED_TASK  ON TASK.id_task=ASSIGNED_TASK.id_task 
INNER    JOIN USER ON USER.id_user=ASSIGNED_TASK.id_user 
OR USER.id_user=COMPLETED_TASK.id_user
```

Comment: Show your expected output based on some sample input.

Comment: Use this 
SELECT * FROM TASK 
INNER JOIN COMPLETED_TASK ON TASK.id_task=COMPLETED_TASK.id_task 
INNER     JOIN ASSIGNED_TASK  ON TASK.id_task=ASSIGNED_TASK.id_task 
INNER   JOIN USER ON USER.id_user=ASSIGNED_TASK.id_user 
OR USER.id_user=COMPLETED_TASK.id_user

Comment: i want this id_task ,task name , assigned to user, task tipe  but i really need id_task in each row

Comment: Rakesh Kumar whit this i get 0 rows no resultset easy to understand why

Comment: Would you mind if I modify your question for the sake of clarity? @Lollo

Comment: Have you tried to join the tables one at a time?  Join `Task` and `Assigned_Task`. If there's result, add `User` table.  If it looks good, add the `Completed_Task`.  It could be there's no task that has been completed.  It could be why the query returns empty set.

Answer (score 0):

```
the real problem, is that sql join or more exactly left join,
return all the left table rows,
but return null value for the fieldset, that   not have match in ON clause.

so i must fill a table whit all task,whit this  head
<thead><th>id_task</th><th>Nametask</th><th>Assigned to</th>th>Tipology</th>

and i need for all task the fiedset id_task for edit and delete task.
so seems evry type of join dont give this result whats that the impossiblequery
```